# Reading date with hour and incrementing it in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file with date '2015-06-01-12', how can I get it to increment the hour in shell script? The result I want is '2015-06-01-13'. If its the 23rd hour it has to move forward a date and get 00 as hour.
I was able to do it to date but have so far had not any luck with incrementing hours.

```
currDate=2015-06-02
nextDate=`date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d "$currDate+1 days"`
echo $nextDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is reasonably easy if you keep your date as an epoch (number of seconds since January 1, 1970):

```
$ currDate=$( date +%s -d "2015-06-02 23:00:00" )
$ echo $currDate
1433300400
$ date +%Y-%m-%d-%H -d @$currDate
2015-06-02-23
$ nextDate=$(( $currDate + 3600 )) #adding an hour's worth of seconds
$ date +%Y-%m-%d-%H -d @$nextDate
2015-06-03-00
```